# Copy property file in Elastic Beanstalk instance in tomcat's conf folder on launch of new instance

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a war file (Java web application) in Elastic Beanstalk environment. Application read some settings from a property file that needs to be in conf folder of tomcat.

I am totally blind how that would be possible. I can place that file by SSHing to the instance but that is not good solution as this environment is auto scaling and hence needs to perform this step automatically.

I also want to create some folders, when new instance is launched.

> I only upload packaged war file

My Bean stalk is as follows

```
Configuration

64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.1 running Tomcat 8 Java 8
```

Scaling

```
Environment type: Load balanced, auto scaling
Number instances: 2 - 4
Scale based on Average Latency
Add instance when > 6000000
Remove instance when < 2000000
```